# Remove chars and append them in the end of the string ( C++ )

Tags: c++

How can I erase the first N-th characters in a given string and append them in the end. For example if we have

```
abracadabra
```

and we shift the first 4 characters to the end then we should get

```
cadabraabra
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: The `std::string` class should have all what you need for that. What have you tried and what does not work?

Comment: Read about `std::rotate`.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of earsing them from the front which is expensive there is another way.  We can [rotate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) them in place which is a single O(N) operation.  In this case you want to rotate to the left so we would use

```
std::string text = "abracadabra";
std::rotate(text.begin(), text.begin() + N, text.end());
```

In the above example if `N` is 4 then you get

```
cadabraabra
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2174d80c6b49c63b)</kbd>

Comment: This is not working when i manually type the string in the console. If i hard code it (just like your program)  in my program it rotates but if i expect from the user to type it then nothing happend in the console.

Comment: @KristianKamenov You would have to show me the code you are using.  It should work just fine.  One thing that may be an issue is if N is bigger than the string size then you have an invalid rotate.

Comment: It is working besides the fact that im operating on the new roatated string and when i have to do 2 rotations for example i have to do them on the original string not on the one rotated before. How can I solve this?

Comment: @KristianKamenov You really need to show the code.  Sounds like you might need to do a copy of the string and do the rotation on that copied string.  Asking a new question should be able to get you the help you need.

Comment: @KristianKamenov Please do not do that.  That is not what answers are for.  A new question is the appropriate place.

Comment: @KristianKamenov I saw your deleted answer.  You need to make a copy of `text` each iteration and rotate that copy.  Then you add that into the vector.  This leaves `text` as the string you read in from the input.

Answer (score 1):

You can try an old-fashioned double loop, one char at a time.

```
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {
    char ex_string[] = "abracadabra";
    int pos = 4;
    char a;
    int i, j;

    size_t length = strlen(ex_string);
    for (j = 0; j < pos; j++) {
        a = ex_string[0];
        for (i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
            ex_string[i] = ex_string[i + 1];
        }
        ex_string[length-1]=a;

    }
    printf("%s", ex_string);


}
```

Comment: If `N` is 100, and the length of the string is 101 characters, you would be looping 10,000 times.  In other words, very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "abracadabra" //lets say
int n;
cin>>n;
string temp;
str.cpy(temp,0,n-1);
str.earse(str.begin(),str.begin()+n-1);
str+=temp;
```

Reference

[string::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/)
[string::copy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/copy/)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    int number;
    cin >> number;

    string erasedString = str;
    string remainingString = str.substr(number + 1, strlen(str));

    erasedString.erase(0, number);

    return 0;
}
```